# Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!

Tags: dhcp

ISC isnt running, heres everything I can give you:

Startup:

```
pi@wtfwifi:~ $ sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
pi@wtfwifi:~ $ systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service 
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-11-07 03:58:43 UTC; 5s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2829 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 07 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Nov 07 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: All rights reserved.
Nov 07 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Nov 07 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Nov 07 03:58:43 wtfwifi isc-dhcp-server[2829]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
Nov 07 03:58:43 wtfwifi isc-dhcp-server[2829]:  failed!
Nov 07 03:58:43 wtfwifi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 07 03:58:43 wtfwifi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
Nov 07 03:58:43 wtfwifi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 07 03:58:43 wtfwifi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf:

```
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd for Debian
#
#

# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
ddns-update-style none;

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
#option domain-name "example.org";
#option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
log-facility local7;

#what i added
subnet 100.64.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 100.64.100.5 100.64.100.80;
    option broadcast-address 100.64.100.255;
        option routers 10.64.10.1;
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    option domain-name "local";
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 64.6.64.6, 64.6.65.6;
}



# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the 
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.

#subnet 10.152.187.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#}

# This is a very basic subnet declaration.

#subnet 10.254.239.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range 10.254.239.10 10.254.239.20;
#  option routers rtr-239-0-1.example.org, rtr-239-0-2.example.org;
#}

# This declaration allows BOOTP clients to get dynamic addresses,
# which we don't really recommend.

#subnet 10.254.239.32 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range dynamic-bootp 10.254.239.40 10.254.239.60;
#  option broadcast-address 10.254.239.31;
#  option routers rtr-239-32-1.example.org;
#}

# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
#subnet 10.5.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range 10.5.5.26 10.5.5.30;
#  option domain-name-servers ns1.internal.example.org;
#  option domain-name "internal.example.org";
#  option routers 10.5.5.1;
#  option broadcast-address 10.5.5.31;
#  default-lease-time 600;
#  max-lease-time 7200;
#}

# Hosts which require special configuration options can be listed in
# host statements.   If no address is specified, the address will be
# allocated dynamically (if possible), but the host-specific information
# will still come from the host declaration.

#host passacaglia {
#  hardware ethernet 0:0:c0:5d:bd:95;
#  filename "vmunix.passacaglia";
#  server-name "toccata.fugue.com";
#}

# Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts.   These addresses
# should not also be listed as being available for dynamic assignment.
# Hosts for which fixed IP addresses have been specified can boot using
# BOOTP or DHCP.   Hosts for which no fixed address is specified can only
# be booted with DHCP, unless there is an address range on the subnet
# to which a BOOTP client is connected which has the dynamic-bootp flag
# set.
#host fantasia {
#  hardware ethernet 08:00:07:26:c0:a5;
#  fixed-address fantasia.fugue.com;
#}

# You can declare a class of clients and then do address allocation
# based on that.   The example below shows a case where all clients
# in a certain class get addresses on the 10.17.224/24 subnet, and all
# other clients get addresses on the 10.0.29/24 subnet.

#class "foo" {
#  match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 4) = "SUNW";
#}

#shared-network 224-29 {
#  subnet 10.17.224.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-224.example.org;
#  }
#  subnet 10.0.29.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-29.example.org;
#  }
#  pool {
#    allow members of "foo";
#    range 10.17.224.10 10.17.224.250;
#  }
#  pool {
#    deny members of "foo";
#    range 10.0.29.10 10.0.29.230;
#  }
#}
```

/etc/defaults/isc-dhcp-server:

```
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server
# installed at /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server by the maintainer scripts

#
# This is a POSIX shell fragment
#

# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
DHCPD_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
DHCPD_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid

# Additional options to start dhcpd with.
#   Don't use options -cf or -pf here; use DHCPD_CONF/ DHCPD_PID instead
#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#   Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="wlan0"
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
# allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

#auto wlan0

#what i added (just some wlano crap.)
iface wlan0 inet static
  alow-hotplug wlan0
  address 192.168.42.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 100.64.100.0
#the crap to run nat (i added it)
up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
#More Ipv6 crap
#iface wlan0 inet6 static
#  address 2606:700:e:31::1
#  netmask 64
```

Syslog:

```
pi@wtfwifi:~ $ tail -n 30 /var/log/syslog 
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2839]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.5
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: All rights reserved.
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: 
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: No subnet declaration for wlan0 (192.168.42.1).
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: ** Ignoring requests on wlan0.  If this is not what
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]:    to which interface wlan0 is attached. **
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: 
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: 
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: 
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: 
Nov  7 03:58:41 wtfwifi dhcpd[2841]: exiting.
Nov  7 03:58:43 wtfwifi isc-dhcp-server[2829]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
Nov  7 03:58:43 wtfwifi isc-dhcp-server[2829]:  failed!
Nov  7 03:58:43 wtfwifi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov  7 03:58:43 wtfwifi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
Nov  7 03:58:43 wtfwifi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov  7 03:58:43 wtfwifi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov  7 04:17:01 wtfwifi CRON[2877]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT 2020: This was made when I was much younger and I would not consider this to be very accurate. This probably will cause problems, especially with modern versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a idiot, Subnet cant be  100.64.100.0, made it  100.64.100.1 and it works

Comment: Didn't work for me... Changing the last zero to a one resulted in a configuration error

Comment: Don't forget to have something actually plugged in to that port!